# Print table of contents without "Contents" header

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have a small table of contents made with `titletoc` that looks like this:

[image]

There are only those three sections (maybe one or two more) but the documentation could get quite long so I'd like easy hyperlinks up top.

I can remove the linked **Contents** line with `\tableofcontents*`, I just forgot for the screenshot.

What I would like to know is, **how can I completely remove the large Contents header?** I can make it empty with `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}`, but then there's just an enormous space.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{memoir}

% Hyperref
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{citecolor=red}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{section} % Section
[0em]                  % Left
{\space}               % Above code
{\thecontentslabel~}   % Numbered format
{}                     % Numberless format
{}                     % Filler
[\hspace{1em}]         % Separator

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}

\begin{document}

    Foo

    \tableofcontents*

    \section{One}
    \section{Two}   
    \section{Three}     

\end{document}
```

I want `1 One 2 Two 3 Three` to be one line break below `Foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title of the table of contents is set by macro `\@tocmaketitle` in `memoir`. This macro can be redefined to remove the title including the space:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{memoir}

% Hyperref
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=red}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{section} % Section
[0em]                  % Left
{\space}               % Above code
{\thecontentslabel~}   % Numbered format
{}                     % Numberless format
{}                     % Filler
[\hspace{1em}]         % Separator

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@tocmaketitle}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Foo

    \tableofcontents*

    \section{One}
    \section{Two}
    \section{Three}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]